# I am having a gambrel roof added to my ranch

Tags: structural-engineering

I am having a gambrel roof added to my 32 × 32 ranch. Upon taking the old roof off, it was noticed that all the wiring for the original first floor was from overhead.

So my contractor built a 6" ("Knee wall" he called it) on top of the old 32 x 32 square plate. Then he laid 32' long I beams spanning the 32' distance with Support from a carrying wall below where possible.

So now there is a gap between the first floor ceiling joists, and the TJ I beams.

I don't care about the gap as it makes it easy to add any new wiring to the first floor if/when needed.

But is this a common practice for making space between floors in wood frame residential construction?

Is it an accepted practice when old utilities for the original house are found above the ceiling in the old house?

Comment: This looks like a qestion for https://diy.stackexchange.com rather than Engineering.